# Does Ubuntu use security features like DEP and ALSR?

Tags: kernel, security

I often read that features such as DEP (Data Execution Prevention) and ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization) are provided on Windows. On Windows, you are given some control over turning on DEP for 32-bit programs.

- Are these features available in Ubuntu
- is there anything we need to do to turn these features on?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes for both. They are on by default; you don't need to do anything to enable it. Longer answer follows...

DEP is used by default in Ubuntu. This is done via the NX bit if the CPU supports it, or emulated via memory segmentation if the CPU does not support it. For more details, see the [non-executable memory feature item](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#nx).

ASLR is used by default in Ubuntu on any memory segments that can be relocated (stack, libraries, heap, mmap). The only portion of a program that is not relocatable by default is the main code area ("text" segment). Programs need to be specially compiled as PIE (position independent executable) to enable this. Many sensitive programs are already built this way. For more details, see [the list](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/BuiltPIE)

Many additional security features are also available by default in Ubuntu. See the [Ubuntu Security Features documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features) for the full list.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel, by default, does make use of similar technologies, however they are different from the Windows versions. If your processor has the capability to set the NX bit (most modern CPUs), then the kernel will make use of it. There is also a weak implementation in ASLR in the kernel, and stronger ones can be installed, but are not installed by default on Ubuntu.

Comment: I can't find references at the moment (the Wikipedia article  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR doesn't have the bits of entropy comparison), but my understanding is that Windows ASLR is weaker than Linux. And if you want heavier-duty ASLR than the Linux default, you can build your own kernel the PaX patchset, which offers higher entropy at a small compatibility cost.

Comment: A good article breaking down the differences https://www.cert.org/blogs/certcc/post.cfm?EntryID=191 of course, that wouldn't be complete with some debating of the finer details :D http://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/comments/1xjwde/differences_between_aslr_on_windows_and_linux

Answer (score 0):

Generally and simply speaking, you would need a PAE version of the kernel for this. For detailed information on this topic see [this summary](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features).

Comment: PAE is only needed for hardware NX. 64bit is already PAE, so on 32bit if you aren't running a PAE kernel, or your hardware lacks the NX bit, Ubuntu emulates the NX feature using memory segmentation.

Comment: @Kees Cook: Thanks for the info. OP asked about the 32bit. On my system (ubuntu 10.10 32bit) `dmesg` says `NX (Execute Disable) protection cannot be enabled: non-PAE kernel`. On the other hand, when I ran tests from http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-bugcontrol/qa-regression-testing/master/files/head%3A/scripts/kernel-security/nx/ , nx seemed to be enforced, but not for the `-pie` and `-rie` tests. So it's a little confusing for me.

Comment: unfortunately, 10.10 and later's dmesg report has a bug where it doesn't say when NX emulation is enabled on hardware with NX but without a PAE kernel: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/ubuntu-maverick.git;a=blob;f=arch/x86/mm/setup_nx.c;h=f0686769a0ada41eba88caf4e4285f6c3ec15454;hb=HEAD#l69

Comment: (This has been reported as a bug now: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/745181)