# Which Ubuntu Source file implements the management of the nx bit?

Tags: security

As I understand it, Ubuntu has a feature to set the nx bit to prevent stack smashing attacks.

What source code file implements this, and during normal operations what process/data structure handles the setting of this bit?

Note: This is *not* a question about writing nx bit protection in 3rd party programs, it is a question about where I can see the implementation of the current protections.

Comment: It is part of the kernel See http://askubuntu.com/questions/32441/does-ubuntu-use-security-features-like-dep-and-alsr It is somewhat unclear what you are asking mind you.

Comment: While this question is on topic here, I feel that you'll get much better answers over at [Unix.SE](//unix.stackexchange.com/), as this question 1) is independent of a particular Linux distribution and 2) pertains to basic inner workings of the Linux kernel.

Comment: I tried there first actually. As I understand it ubuntu implemented nx support separate from the main Kernal at one point anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to start [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h).

**Example how to start**

There is line of code:

```
#define X86_FEATURE_NX      ( 1*32+20) /* Execute Disable */
```

I already has cloned git repo of linux kernel, it was cloned when the last commit in `master` branch was `14186fea0cb06bc43181ce239efe0df6f1af260a`. So something may be changed right now.

Trying to find all files that use this `X86_FEATURE_NX` in the linux kernel git repo:

```
$ for i in *; do find "$i" -type f | xargs grep -l "X86_FEATURE_NX"; done
arch/x86/kvm/vmx.c
arch/x86/kvm/svm.c
arch/x86/kernel/head_32.S
arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h
```